# Getting data from two separate models in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to get data which is related to an id and I used the `find($id)` method to get those data, now I wanna get data from two tables which have one to many relationship.

How can I get data which is related to the same id from two table?

I try to this way but it hasn't worked:

```
public function show($id)
{

    $post=Clients::find($id);

    return view('pet.shw',['post'=>$post,'pets'=>$post->pets]);
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2016-how-to-get-data-from-one-to-many-relation This might help you

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use `with()` I have simple solution but maybe not best solution:

`Post::with('pets')->where('id',$id)->first();`

Maybe below code is work to i dont test it:

`Post::with('pets')->find($id)`;

Of course you should have `comments` method in your `Post` Object:

```
 public function pets(){

   return $this->hasMany(Pet::class);
}
```

hope help

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define a relationship between your `Client` model and `Pet` model

So, in `App\Client`, you would have the following relationship:

```
public function pets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Pet::class); 
}
```

and in `App\Pet`, you would have the following relationship:

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class)
}
```

You should then be able to do this in your Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Client::with('pets')->find($id);

    return view('pet.shw')
        ->withPost($post);
}
```

and accesses your relationship like this in the `pet.shw` view:

```
foreach($post->pets as $pet) {}
```

For more information read about [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)